# Mojolicious parameter validation: optional with an empty value

Tags: perl, mojolicious

In my app I use the validation to verify and filter my input data before using the validated data to be saved to the DB (using DBIX::Class).

I have a few optional fields, but when these are empty they never show up in the validated output, which can be a problem if the edit to be saved went from a having a filled in optional field to an empty optional field. Then the empty data is not picked up in the output.

Is there a proper appoach to handling these from the validation side of things? Like telling the validator that the value is undef/empty string and that the field is valid. Or what is a good approach to this?

For saving an edit I'd like to just feed the passed fields into the proper `DBIx::Class::Row` object and update it. Thus the missing empty optional fields is a problem.

Here is a minimal example of using the validation:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Modern::Perl;
use Mojolicious::Validator;

my $validator = Mojolicious::Validator -> new;
my $v         = $validator -> validation;

$v -> input({foo => '', bar => 'bar' });

$v -> optional('foo');
$v -> required('bar');


for my $f ( @{ $v -> failed } ) {
  say sprintf '"%s" failed validation, reason: "%s"', $f, $v -> error($f) -> [0];
}

for my $f ( @{ $v -> passed } ) {
  say sprintf '"%s" passed validation, value: "%s"', $f, $v -> param($f);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, seems `$v -> output( { %{ $v -> output }, 'foo' => '' } );` is one approach, seems a bit hackish though